# How to remove Minitube completely to scratch?

Tags: 12.04, uninstall, software-installation, purge

I tried to completely remove and re-install Minitube for personal issues and I did it with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge minitube-*
```

But after re-installation I got all history and subscriptions back. From where did it withdraw this config? How can I make it look clean as it's like was installed for the first time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

apt-get remove will only remove files declared as part of the package installation, not your data files. Your data files are somewhere in your home directory, usually in a hidden directory. Look for a directory named `.minitube` or something similar (yes, it starts with a dot). Use `ls -la` to list all files, including hidden ones.

Once you find it, you can remove it with `rm -rf .minitube` (or whatever the directory name is).

Comment: thank you! You made me to look there again because I actually knew about this I mean `.minitube` in hidden Home directory. The reason is or was now that there's NO any folder named Minitube and I couldn't find it using `ls` `-la` nothing helped because it's named way differently :-) For those who also be looking it's located in `/home/.local/share/data`